# PHP to feed the json_decode() function with an PHP Array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a proper `.json` physical file and i read it from PHP by parsing it.

Let's say the `sales.json` contains:

```
{
    "custid" : "7761", 
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemcode"  : "A11231G",
            "suppliers" : [
                {
                    "id" : "s10001",
                    "name" : "Benny & John",
                },
                            {
                    "id" : "s10004",
                    "name" : "Colorado Dimension",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then i consume it from PHP:

```
$sales = json_decode( file_get_contents("store/sales.json"), true );
```

There is no problem and `$sales` is already become an Array which is ok.

Now for some reason, i want to feed that `json_decode()` function with an PHP Array (instead of the `.json` physical file).

---

I know it is the dumb way that i am actually doing like converting, `Array` -> `json` -> `Array`, which is finally `Array` to `Array`.

---

But for whatever reason i have,

- Even if i have a PHP Array() *with the correct structure*, if i use `json_encode($phpArray)`, then to feed as `json_decode( json_encode($phpArray), true )`, will it give the exact object like i get from `json_decode("sales.json")` file?
- (or) how can i feed the `json_decode` function with a PHP `Array()` object i have?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What ***exactly*** are you trying to achieve?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ says its not a valid json which is posted on the question.

Comment: you can store the array in a file with serialize() then unserialize and json encode http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/5/11/0

Comment: Why not change your array directly?

Comment: @xdazz (not really but you can imagine) the php file which contains `$sales = json_decode( file_get_contents("store/sales.json"), true );` (designed to read from json file) is not in your control. Means, in some condition that you can not change the function written there. Then i MUST feed the function with JSON only.

Comment: @シリウス So what is the input, the array or the json string or the path of the json file?

Comment: The function is designed to read from `json` "file". (with very very long and complex object dimensions inside) But i don't want to feed him from a file now. I have PHP Array. (But i dont want the current `$sale` final Array Output to be changed in result, after i feed from a PHP Array) So can you find a way, how to properly feed that function with PHP Array i have?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, json_decode returns a STD object, not an array. To get an array from a JSON string you need to use `json_decode($string, true)`.

Comment: Well, look at his code: `json_decode( file_get_contents("settings/config.json"), true );`

Comment: Hi Wordpress Developer, i'm not asking about getting Array from JSON. I'm asking about converting `PHP Array -> JSON Encoded -> JSON Decode -> PHP Array`.

Comment: You can safely assume that json_encode of an existing array, followed by a json_decode of the resulting string will produce the same array, with one exception: all elements in the input array must be serializable.